# как проверить является ли дата последним днем месяца?

Tags: java

например есть дата String date= 02.02.2022;

LocalDate localDate = DateTimeUtils.stringToLocalDate(date,"dd.MM.yyyy");

Comment: Завести массив из 12 чисел и смотреть в нем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать методы `LocalDate::getDayOfMonth` и `LocalDate::lengthOfMonth`:

```java
public static boolean isLastDayOfMonth(LocalDate ld) {
    return ld.getDayOfMonth() == ld.lengthOfMonth();
}
```

Или же можно сравнить данную дату с датой, полученной при помощи [`TemporalAdjusters::lastDayOfMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#lastDayOfMonth--):

```java
public static boolean isLastDayOfMonth(LocalDate ld) {
    return ld.isEqual(ld.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()));
}
```

Или при помощи `LocalDate::withDayOfMonth` и `LocalDate::lengthOfMonth`:

```java
public static boolean isLastDayOfMonth(LocalDate ld) {
    return ld.isEqual(ld.withDayOfMonth(ld.lengthOfMonth()));
}
```

Comment: Nowhere Man. спасибо)